# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, yii

First i have searched it over internet, it has been asked before but no solution there.
  
I have deployed a yii aplication on server. It is working great on local machine. But now it is giving me error `CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user`
I have also created a user in phpmyadmin and assigned privileges to it as shown in figure
[image]

In my database.php i have written

```
'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=allspice_flk_embroidery',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'allspice_afnan',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
```

Is it related to server? Or something i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why it happened but i have found a solution for it.
 1. Create a user and assign privileges.
 2. Now create a database(Dont create tables)
 3. Assign user to this database.
 4. Now create tables.

If you have created database before making a user then drop the database and follow the above process.

Answer (score 0):

**Better more explanation will be more helpful.**
I hope you have managed somewhat you are not saying `Yii` to access local database with the same database name in your local server.

However, the error says, you are trying to access the database with the username you have not permitted to.

Test database connection from your terminal first:

```
mysql -h<hostname> -u<username> -p [Enter]
```

Type your password.

If you have same kind of error, then you definately have problem with either username/password or host you are trying to connect to.

Check hostname, username and password twice and try to connect. Even, better try with the port you have assigned for the particular user.